# Using the value of a variable as the name of an object

Tags: python, class

How can I use the value of a variable as the object in a class?

e.g. I have a class called 'a', and I want to be able to assign the value of a variable 'b' to be the name of an object in class a

```
class a():
   __init__(self):

b = "foo"
```

How can I make it so that

```
b = a()
```

Would be the same as

```
foo = a()
```

?

Comment: .... what? I do not understand what you mean. `b = a()` is *the same* as `foo = a()`... do you mean `b = foo()`?

Comment: I think OP wants to create a variable named after the value of another variable

Answer (score 4):

The recommended way of doing that kind of thing is to rather use a dictionnary. Like so :

```
b = "foo"
myDictionnary = {}

myDictionnary[b] = a

print(myDictionnary["foo"])
```

Answer (score 1):

What you seek is unarguably a bad practice, but if you must...

This can only be done on the global scope. You'll need to add your new variable to the `globals()` dictionary:

```
class a:
   pass

b = 'foo'

globals()[b] = a()

print foo
# <__main__.a instance at 0x10282d518>
```

This also works inside functions:

```
class a:
    pass

b = 'foo'

# Be careful with this. As I said, this updates the global scope
# So "foo" can actually be accessed out of the function.
# Furthermore, calling this function more than once will yield
# different results as globals()['foo'] keeps getting overriden
def some_method():
    globals()[b] = a()
    print foo
    # <__main__.a instance at 0x10282d5a8>

some_method()
```

Comment: Modifying `locals()` [doesn't work](https://ideone.com/Hv0Xwu). Please read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) before posting. That applies to answers as well as questions.

Comment: @user2357112 You are correct on that. Updated answer